# Downloading file programmatically with HTTP authentication

Tags: php, http, basic-authentication

I want to download a file (e.g. http://rapidpich.ir/d/555864) programmatically using php. However, when I attempt to follow the link in my web browser, I'm asked for a username and password.

How can I provide these credentials in PHP and retrieve the file?

[image: Authentication dialog in Windows]

Comment: It is really hard to understand what your question is. I was going to attempt to edit this, but it is very difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get remote content and then save it to your server, if this is what you really want?

Comment: You need to ask the owner of that file for permission to download it.

Comment: @prolink007: I don't see how this isn't clear. He wants to programmatically retrieve the contents of a webpage that's protected by HTTP authentication. Seems pretty simple to me. Did you bother viewing the image or following the link? I have edited the question to make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually to grab a file you'd write something like:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("http://url.to/file");
```

You may do something other than store into a variable, or you may use a different function.

If the file is protected by HTTP authentication, you can usually specify the credentials in the URI:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("http://username:password@url.to/file");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to submit form data.

Take a look here [cURL tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) and here [php cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: What does form data have to do with it?

Comment: good advise for https